# Automatic backup with Back in Time?

Tags: backup

I have installed Back In Time Backup Application and configured to backup one important folder every day into another folder.

**Question.**

1. Does it perform backup operation only when the application is open(or launched)?
2. Should I launch this application every time I log in to Ubuntu?
3. If YES, how can I make it to run automatically every time I log in to Ubuntu?

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Well I think your question should be answered, right :)? Maybe you should mark it as such. Thanks for asking it btw., just had exactly the same problem!

Comment: Maybe this would be of interest: http://askubuntu.com/questions/719031/how-to-make-silent-backups-when-plugging-in-a-usb-disk-and-when-using-back-in-ti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation at: http://backintime.le-web.org/documentation/ Back In Time uses cron to schedule the backups, so you should not need to be logged in for the backup to take place.

Comment: Also, if you would like a simple gui way to see your cron jobs install GNOME Schedule.  It's in the official repositories.  Once you open it you will see your Back In Time cron job and can edit it to more suit your needs since the scheduling in BIT is pretty generic (it schedules everything at midnight, and if your computer is off cron jobs don't run).

Comment: @Deadite81. Thanks for the good advice. I really didn't know about that. One question please. Let's imagine that I scheduled to perform automatic backup every day at 14-00. What happens if at this time my computer is turned off. Will it perform that missed operation of backup automatically once I turn on my computer back? Or that operation will be missed?

Comment: Unfortunately, if the scheduled backup time is missed because the computer is off, the backup will not take place. You could set up more frequent backups to increase the likelihood that a backup will be made. This would result in more backups, which may be undesirable, but would also allow you to be better able to restore a file to a previous state since you will have more backed up versions.

Answer (score 0):

If your kernel supports “inotify” and you have the Python scripting language loaded, an interesting alternative for essentially real-time backup of a folder is inosync, a Python script, provided by the author, Benedikt Böhm from Germany (http://bb.xnull.de/).  You modify his sample configuration file to point at your source and target folders and inosync runs in the background, using rsync to keep the target updated with changes on the source.