# udev rule for android not working with go-mtpfs

Tags: 12.04, android, udev

On Ubuntu 12.04, my rule fires a script called `motoe.sh` when a Motorola Moto E is connected to the machine USB port. My custom rule does not work.

The rule is:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2e76", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/motoe.sh"
```

`motoe.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

motoemount.sh & motoedesktop.sh
```

`motoemount.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

go-mtpfs /media/MyAndroid
```

`motoedesktop.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

gmessage -center -timeout 3 -buttons OK:0 "message to "

rdesktop -u username -d domain -r disk:motoe=/media/MyAndroid/Interno/Download ip_address -a 8 -k pt-br

gmessage -center -timeout 3 -buttons OK:0 "another message to the user" &
umount /media/MyAndroid/
```

All the .sh scripts have the execution permission set.

I tried to use SUBSYSTEM, SUBSYSTEMS, with DRIVER without DRIVER, and no effect.

I don't figure what I missed out. If I execute `motoe.sh` from a terminal, it runs correctly.

Comment: I tried without the gmessage, but result in no effect. I tried to point directly to motoemount.sh, but I still get the same result.

Thank your for your guidance.

Comment: Glad I could help a bit, JPDev. (A) Feedback on what the problem(s) was/were is not obligatory, but would be nice in the form of a concise but pregnant comment to my answer. (B) I flagged yr last message "It's working now. Cbhihe, thank you again for your time and answer, it helped me a lot." because you published it as an _answer_ when it really should be a _comment_. AU frowns upon that.  We try to keep things simple and you should expect it to be deleted.  --- Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I'm new to AskUbuntu, it'll not happen again.

Comment: No worries at all JPDev. I was just highlighting some of the dos and don'ts, knowing you propably weren't aware of them. ;-)  AU _always_ welcome newcomers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-1- Be careful when you run an external program as `udev` execution will be suspended during the external program's execution. Better said, it will wait until the external program exits before proceeding. You can still execute a long winded program but you must "detach" it immediately, by running it in the background. In yr case, yr `motoe.sh` should probably read:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ 
   motoemount.sh
   motoedesktop.sh
} &
```

which is equivalent to `{ motoemount.sh; motoedesktop.sh }&`, i.e. executing `motoedesktop.sh` *unconditionnally* after `motoemount.sh` has exited.

Note that :

```
$ motoemount.sh &; motoedesktop.sh
```

means that `motoemount.sh` and `motoedesktop.sh` are executed asynchronously, i.e. `motoedesktop.sh` starts executing before `motoemount.sh` even exits.

```
$ motoemount.sh && motoedesktop.sh
```

is not the same. In that case, `motoedesktop.sh` executes ONLY if the exit value of `motoemount.sh` is "0".

> [....] If I execute motoe.sh from a terminal, it runs correctly

-2- `udev` does not run external programs on any active terminal, and it does not execute them under the context of a shell. Be sure to ensure your program is marked executable, if it is a shell script ensure it starts with an appropriate shebang (e.g. #!/bin/sh). The environment that `udev` sees will not be the same environment you (or whoever $USER) is gets on the console. So specify absolute paths for all your commands:

`motoemount.sh`  -> `/path/to/motoemount.sh`
`motoedesktop.sh`  -> `/path/to/motoedesktop.sh`
`go-mtpfs` -> ...
`gmessage` -> ...
`rdesktop` -> ...
`umount`  -> `/bin/umount`

In order to find a path for system cmds (such as `umount`) you can use the cmd `which [cmd]` without brackets, e.g.:

```
$ which umount
/bin/umount
```

-3- Verify that yr process has sufficient privileges to unmount `/media/MyAndroid/`

> [....] If I execute motoe.sh from a terminal, it runs correctly

-4- If you print to screen (not sure you do, as I'm not familiar with `gmessage` but it looks like you do), make sure your DISPLAY environment variable is set (known to udev) and exported (passed on to sub-shells). Otherwise do not expect any standard output to appear on your terminal. For an example see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719031/how-to-make-silent-backups-when-plugging-in-a-usb-disk-and-when-using-back-in-ti), in particular the `# set DISPLAY` section.

Comment: Cbhihe, thank you for your time and detailed answer to my question. I made some changes. All the scripts are marked as executable, for test purpouses I removed the gmessage, but still not working.