# Execute command when USB device is added

Tags: usb, mouse, udev

I have a razer deathadder mouse connected to my ubuntu 15.10 laptop. This mouse uses 3500 DPI per default which his way to fast. Using `razercfg` I'm able to set this to 1800 DPI, so no problem here. 
Unfortunately, this options is not preserved over reboots or even suspend-to-ram/disk (laptop closed). My first thought was to call `razercfg` on login, but as I said this does not work if with suspend-to-ram/disk.
Therefore I thought about using udev rules:

`lsusb` tells me:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f2:b39a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 1532:0016 Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder Mouse
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 17ef:100f Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04b4:0101 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Keyboard/Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Using the vendor and product ID, I created a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/100-razer-deathadder.rules` containing:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1532", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0016", RUN+="razercfg -p 1 -r 1:1800"
```

which should set the appropriate DPI for the mouse when added to the system. The command `razercfg -p 1 -r 1:1800`is tested and works. 
I reloaded the rules with `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`.

However, it does not work. Indeed, `udevadm monitor` confirms, that this rule does not seem to fire.

Any idea whats the mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Go into `/dev/input/` and query the input devices that are most likely to correspond to your mouse, with the terminal cmd:

```
 $ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/input/yr-device-file-name
```

You will be able to identify it using the two environment variables (env-var)

- ID_VENDOR_ID=1532
- MODEL_ID=0016

per your question (depending on yr device, the 2nd env-var may not show).

**2)** Identify the value of the env-var `SUBSYSTEM` and add it to yr udev rule.

**3)** Add the absolute path for the executable `razercfg`.

So yr udev rule should read something like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="___", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1532", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0016", RUN+="/path/to/razercfg -p 1 -r 1:1800"
```

Remember that udev does not execute in a shell environment, so it may not know  (mostly does not know) of PATHS and other environment settings you may have come to depend on as a login user. That includes printing to stdout (FD1), unless you make provisions for that by correctly setting `DISPLAY` and exporting it from within the udev rule, i.e. from within a wrapper script that executes `razercfg`... (See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728885/udev-rule-for-android-not-working-with-go-mtpfs/729089#729089) AU answer for a redacted summary on that particular aspect and read about udevadm on `man udevadm` if you have not done so already).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did what you suggested, but still no luck. I found my mouse under `/dev/input/mouse2` with `E: SUBSYSTEM=input`, so I have now the following rule:
 `SUBSYSTEM="input", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1532", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0016", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/razercfg -p 1 -r 1:1800"`. Still not working

Comment: @user1228633: Careful, yr udev rule should read `SUBSYSTEM=="input", ... `with 2 "=" ! When you run `razercfg` from terminal (not from udev), does it open a GUI for you ? Is it interactive in any way ? or does it exit quietly ?

Comment: Ah, yeha sure! That typo fixed the problem. However, another occurred. Apparently `razercfg` causes to add/remove the device for configuration, which results in `udev` firing an `add` rule. Which again executes `razercfg`.... So  I basically get an infinity loop. Is there a way to make my original rule maybe more strictly or something like that?

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem. Just wrote a simple script saving the last time `razercfg` run in a file in `/tmp`. If `razercfg` did not run in the last two seconds, than run it executes `razercfg` and save the time.